# Perl: Regular Expression Matching

Tags: regex, perl

Say I have a **fixed** variable:

```
$f_variable = "hello.exe";
```

and I want to search through a file line by line and find the path that contains this word, for example:

```
/Desktop/Downloads/hello.exe
```

or

```
/Desktop/Downloads/hello_qwdqd.exe
```

Lets say that the file extension can be either `exe` or `ex`

and i wrote this line of code:

```
 if ($line =~ m/(\/$f_variable.*\.[exe]+)
```

obviously it won't works because the line of code above is actually:

```
if ($line =~ m/(\/hello.exe.*\.[exe]+)
```

which will not match anything.

So my question is what changes should I make in order to match and capture the whole path properly **without** changing the value of `$f_variable`?

Comment: See [File::Basename](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Basename).

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote isn't even a complete regex. Though you've not said clearly what's in the file (Are the lines just paths?), you probably want something like:

```
my $pattern = $f_variable;
$pattern =~ s/\.exe?$//;
if ($line =~ m{(/\S*\Q$pattern\E[^/]*\.exe?)}) {
  print "$1\n";
}
```

This removes the file name `.ex` or `.exe` suffix to get the base name, then matches the first string that contains the base name including any non-space leading characters and trailing non-space characters ending in `.ex` or `.exe`.

Comment: May I ask what is the function of `$` in the second line beside `.exe?`?

Comment: its end of condition